# dropdown question

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

What is wrong with this ?

```
<%=Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Client,null,"Select",new { @style = "width: 630px" })%>
```

There is a ViewData["Client"] which contanins the source , the dropdown is filled but is not selected the value corresponding to Model.Client

Answer (score 3):

Change ViewDate["Client"] to ViewData["ClientList"] and put it instead of null .Dont forget to cast it to SelectList.

```
<%=Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.ClientId,(SelectList)ViewData["ClientList"],"Select",new { @style = "width: 630px" })%>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Check out this link for best practice :http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2010/01/18/drop-down-lists-and-asp-net-mvc.aspx